# Conditionally extending a template in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a download page on a Django site that I want to serve for both users who are logged in and who aren't. Instead of having a user_download.html and login_download.html, I want to have a single download.html that conditionally extends the correct base.

However, I get an error when I use the following code.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  {% extends 'user_base.html' %}
{% else %}
  {% extends 'login_base.html' %}
{% endif %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Downloadable content</h2> 
...
{% endblock %}
```

The error I receive is 
TemplateSyntaxError at /download/

Invalid block tag: 'else'

What's wrong with the else? I tried

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  {% extends 'user_base.html' %}
{% else %}{% if AnonymousUser.is_authenticated %}
  {% extends 'login_base.html' %}
{% endif %}{% endif %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Downloadable content</h2> 
...
{% endblock %}
```

but this didn't work, either.

Thanks,
erip

Comment: The normal way to handle this situation is to have two separate templates, and check if they are authenticated in the `view`, then render the appropriate template.

Comment: @mattm That's how I was doing it earlier, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it to avoid multiple files. If there's not a better way, I'll continue doing that.

Comment: Doing it in the `view` is "how it's done." The reason what you're trying to do isn't working is because you need to define `extends` at the beginning of the template. Imagine writing a class which is a subclass, but not specifying at the outset the class it inherits from. You're basically trying to do the same thing here.

Comment: That makes sense. If you add it as an answer, I'll mark it answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `{% extends %}` tag supports variables. See [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#extends) for reference.

```
def my_view(request):
   if request.user.is_authenicated
       base_template_name = 'user_base.html'
   else:
       base_template_name = 'login_base.html'

   # Pass base template name to the renderer
   return render_to_response('your_template.html', {'base_template_name':base_template_name})
```

Template (please note that the value is not quoted):

```
{% extends base_template_name %}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because `extends` needs to be defined at the top of the template. `extends` controls template inheritance: you are basically creating a subclass from some parent class, which is why `extends` needs to be the first thing in the template.

Imagine writing a class, and in the `__init__()` you said something like

```
class DoesntKnowWhereToInheritFrom(object):

    def __init__():
        if something:
            self.inherits_from(x)
        else
            self.inherits_from(y)
```

The compiler/interpreter would *freak out*.

The common way to do what you are trying to do here is to check for `is_authenticated` in the `view`, and then render the appropriate template.

Comment: Basically this does not answer the question.